# redirect http to https using .htaccess failing

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website which uses CloudFlare flexible SLL hosted on HostGator.

I want to redirect *all* HTTP requests to corresponding HTTPS URL. No exceptions. I intend to put the rule at top with **L**, so when it’s handled all following rewrite rules should not be tested.

My current code is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

But that results in endless redirects to the HTTPS version. Here is FireFox Live HTTP Headers:

> https://example.net/
>
> **GET / HTTP/1.1**
>   **Host:** example.net
>   **User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
>   **Accept:** text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   **Accept-Language:** da,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
>   **Accept-Encoding:** gzip, deflate, br
>   **DNT:** 1
>   **Connection:** keep-alive
>   **Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:** 1
>
> **HTTP/2.0 301 Moved Permanently**
>   **Date:** Wed, 15 Feb 2017 15:20:35 GMT
>   **Content-Type:** text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>   **Set-Cookie:** __cfduid=d07edac1644bccce1642d2c845767f9951487172035; expires=Thu, 15-Feb-18 15:20:35 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.net; HttpOnly
>   **Location:** https://example.net/
>   **Server:** cloudflare-nginx
>   **cf-ray:** 3319bea4dd2f3cfb-CPH
>   **X-Firefox-Spdy:** h2
>
> ---
>
> http://ocsp.digicert.com/
>
> **POST / HTTP/1.1**
>   **Host:** ocsp.digicert.com
>   **User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
>   **Accept:** text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   **Accept-Language:** da,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
>   **Accept-Encoding:** gzip, deflate
>   **Content-Length:** 83
>   **Content-Type:** application/ocsp-request
>   **DNT:** 1
>   **Connection:** keep-alive 0Q0O0M0K0I0    +
>
> **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**
>   **Accept-Ranges:** bytes
>   **Cache-Control:** public, max-age=172800
>   **Content-Type:** application/ocsp-response
>   **Date:** Wed, 15 Feb 2017 15:20:35 GMT
>   **Etag:** "58a44f61-1d7"
>   **Expires:** Wed, 22 Feb 2017 03:20:35 GMT
>   **Last-Modified:** Wed, 15 Feb 2017 12:53:53 GMT
>   **Server:** ECS (arn/459D)
>   **X-Cache:** HIT
>   **Content-Length:** 471
>
> ---
>
> https://example.net/
>
> **GET / HTTP/1.1**
>   **Host:** example.net
>   **User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
>   **Accept:** text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   **Accept-Language:** da,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
>   **Accept-Encoding:** gzip, deflate, br
>   **Cookie:** __cfduid=d07edac1644bccce1642d2c845767f9951487172035
>   **DNT:** 1
>   **Connection:** keep-alive
>   **Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:** 1
>
> **HTTP/2.0 301 Moved Permanently**
>   **Date:** Wed, 15 Feb 2017 15:20:35 GMT
>   **Content-Type:** text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>   **Location:** https://example.net/
>   **Server:** cloudflare-nginx
>   **cf-ray:** 3319bea7ddfb3cfb-CPH
>   **X-Firefox-Spdy:** h2
>
> ---
>
> https://example.net/
>
> **GET / HTTP/1.1**
>   **Host:** example.net
>   **User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
>   **Accept:** text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   **Accept-Language:** da,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
>   **Accept-Encoding:** gzip, deflate, br
>   **Cookie:** __cfduid=d07edac1644bccce1642d2c845767f9951487172035
>   **DNT:** 1
>   **Connection:** keep-alive
>   **Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:** 1
>
> **HTTP/2.0 301 Moved Permanently**
>   **Date:** Wed, 15 Feb 2017 15:20:36 GMT
>   **Content-Type:** text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>   **Location:** https://example.net/
>   **Server:** cloudflare-nginx
>   **cf-ray:** 3319beaaae7e3cfb-CPH
>   **X-Firefox-Spdy:** h2

I have seen other similar questions, but most suggested solutions are a variation of what I currently use, and I have tried them (but do please feel free to recommend whatever worked for you, and I will try it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Cloudflare Flexible SSL**: secure connection between your visitor and CloudFlare, but **no secure connection between CloudFlare and your web server**. You don't need to have an SSL certificate on your web server, but your visitors still see the site as being HTTPS enabled. [Source](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416)

Because you redirect to HTTPS from your server, rather than with a Cloudflare page rule, even HTTPS requests by the client will still always trigger the redirect rule.

```
1. Client ---> HTTP ----> Cloudflare CDN ----> HTTP ----> Your server
                                                                 | 
                         <-------  Response: Redirect to HTTPS <- 

2. Client ---> HTTPS ----> Cloudflare CDN ----> HTTP ----> Your server
                                                                 | 
                         <-------  Response: Redirect to HTTPS <-

3. Client ---> HTTPS ----> Cloudflare CDN ----> HTTP ----> Your server
                                                                 | 
                         <-------  Response: Redirect to HTTPS <-
```

Cloudflare doesn't talk HTTPS to your webserver and that creates an Infinite Redirect loop.

To resolve that you'll need to remove the redirect from your .htaccess file and set up a Cloudflare page rule instead.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I will try look in my CloudFlare settings to see what I can do there.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Partially taken from: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26623196/2774776

Comment: Although [this Cloudflare KB article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-) suggests that it will be more efficient to setup a CF page rule.

Comment: Cloudflare is surely the right way to do it, but there's a reason we can have more than one answer :) and the question was specific to .htaccess