# SSL Certificate related - Too many redirects

Tags: ssl, wordpress, ssl-certificate-errors, bitnami, ssl-certificate-renewal

I am using bitnami wordpress website.
I was trying to replace the old SSL certificates files with the new ones.
I did replaced it but now I am getting "too many redirects errors".
Can anyone help me out?
I am using CLoudflare CDN.
When I enable cloudlflare SSL with "Full"" mode the site loads.
but when I change it to "off" the same issue comes back.

I have written my redirect lines/Commands under port 80
and SSL lines/commands under 443.
I have writtedn Servername and server alias in both the ports.

let me know what mistake I am making.
I have tried to give you all the information that I know.

Comment: Fairly typical - your web server redirects from http to https but when connecting over https to cloudflare , cloudflare is still configured to access your site over clear text plain http , which triggers a new redirect. - Configure cloudflare to connect over https and do the redirect from http to https at cloudflare - https://serverfault.com/a/832725

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirect http to https using .htaccess failing](https://serverfault.com/questions/832721/redirect-http-to-https-using-htaccess-failing) - both solutions in the linked duplicate may be usually useful to you