302 redirects on Apache HTTP server
I am running a Netbox instance on an OpenSUSE Leap VM, the default config file comes like this:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # CHANGE THIS TO YOUR SERVER'S NAME
    ServerName netbox.argenmedia.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # CHANGE THIS TO YOUR SERVER'S NAME
    ServerName netbox.argenmedia.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/netbox.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/netbox.key

    Alias /static /opt/netbox/netbox/static

    <Directory /opt/netbox/netbox/static>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location /static>
        ProxyPass !
    </Location>

    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8001/
</VirtualHost>

Apache Enabled modules:
a2enmod -l
actions alias auth_basic authn_core authn_file authz_host authz_groupfile authz_core authz_user autoindex cgi dir env expires include log_config mime negotiation setenvif ssl socache_shmcb userdir reqtimeout proxy proxy_http headers mod_rewrite

Apache logs:
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access_log 
172.68.19.15 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:26:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.15 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:26:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.15 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:26:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.15 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:26:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.15 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:26:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.15 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:26:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.15 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:26:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.15 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:26:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
45.79.120.183 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:30:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Debian; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
45.79.120.183 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:30:17 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 9307 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Debian; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"
172.68.19.16 - - [02/Oct/2024:02:31:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15"

Domain is hosted on Cloudflare (proxied) same as other services without any issues.
I do understand there's a loop going on, I do notice the port 80 saying "Rewrite all incoming requests to https" and port 443 saying "Pass this to http: etcetc" So maybe that's where the loop happens?
But why would Netbox ship out with a faulty config file like this?
Or is it some rewrite condition on my Cloudflare settings causing this?
Added info:
netbox:/home/netbox# curl -I http://netbox.argenmedia.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2024 03:31:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://netbox.argenmedia.com/
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v4?s=SuA%2F8OAWIuZ1EUSRCS25njGptptwaWIwIbOTT0k36JQbFNp2JTNA0hk7WhRIbpTg5RS%2FAH%2BPACcZeNXSyEwY5Naw7csJpgKODYi%2F4reBYO042IpJ%2ByT0WlvG5Df%2FBP0pF9vJavAyUMewXg%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
Speculation-Rules: "/cdn-cgi/speculation"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 8cc19e594de1af50-GRU

netbox:/home/netbox# curl -I https://netbox.argenmedia.com
HTTP/2 302 
date: Wed, 02 Oct 2024 03:31:21 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
location: https://netbox.argenmedia.com/
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v4?s=cDg5I7tqtcczMBLItdEEKLUqKqftsq4snsvLMepp%2BCJ1UzK5M8UOlA1jiG6ttXhLuHuyIfe9ZcoZgb8Psp2x6QD6PPgT%2FALYUzyX5VDxeCvGeu98893n0SuK6hzNFeAIdK%2FbrZeqcZ1jMw%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
speculation-rules: "/cdn-cgi/speculation"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 8cc19e78dc4fa4d2-GRU



Check with curl where the redirect goes.

@vidarlo: It goes right to the correct domain (and CF's proxies) and then I get a response like this `< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: https://netbox.argenmedia.com/
< Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https://a.nel.cloudflare.com/report/v4?s=CVp1sDH%2B%2FQ4OOFfcdzrRLUaUkWaucLBEPJZ8bo1Beyshnmh0unfGAMZC98Oq5YzRjoR%2Fv9s2PUKKK0PL8yB8fvoUym3rzMS%2FYluNeOnwIoDbCn2aLMcna1MVcQN0t6JyfbNhwBDs6Gy3mg%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< Speculation-Rules: "/cdn-cgi/speculation"
< Server: cloudflare

What's the actual output of curl -I http://url and curl -I https://url? [Edit] your question to add the information.

@vidarlo: Information added. Thanks for the help!

It redirects properly from http to https. Does the browser enter a redirect loop?

Your problem is likely similar to this https://serverfault.com/a/832725/37681 and you need to reconfigure cloudflare so that it make http rather than https requests to your server and redirect to https at cloudflare rather than on your Own webserver

@ vidarlo: It seems like, yeah! "This page isn’t working
netbox.argenmedia.com redirected you too many times.
Try deleting your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
@HBruijn: Thank you for the input! I will look into it right now and report back. Thanks!

@HBruijn: that seems to have helped! Now i'm running on error 403 but I'm sure that's related to my Apache configuration or permissions on static folder for netbox. I'll investigate Google a bit more to see if I can find some solution. Thanks a lot for the help with Cloudflare!!

@HBruijn: If possible please reply as answer so I can select it as answer!
